# Scroll to end of page with WebExecute

Tags: web-access

I want to scrape the data from this url : https://www.cboe.com/us/indices/indicessearch/

In so doing , I need to scroll to the end of page. Is there a way to use WebExecute to scroll to end of page ? In the mean time, I just manually scroll to the end and extract data using WebExecute,"ElementText".

Thanks

Alan

Comment: Use `"JavascriptExecute"->"window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);"`. [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715646/scroll-automatically-to-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: Thanks. I will try.