# Import Infinite Scrolling Data

Tags: import, data-acquisition

I'm trying to use Import to scrape historical data from Yahoo! finance (*update*: or any other website that uses infinite scrolling). The issue is that the webpage initially only shows 3 months of data and so that's what's imported. If you are browsing, as you scroll down more data is dynamically displayed up to a year. Is there a way in Mathematica to extract the extra data?

*Update Note*: As mentioned in the comments, Yahoo! finance provides a download link, but the general question still stands. It's worth noting, also, that [this problem is solved in python](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/how-crawl-infinite-scrolling-pages-using-python/), but it'd be nice if Mathematica also had a away to do it.

Comment: You don't need to scrape anything, because on Yahoo Finance there's a download button that gives you a .CSV file : for example if you go to ^IXIC (the NASDAQ Composite Index)  on the Historical Data tab there is a download button with this link : https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/%5EIXIC?period1=1609261512&period2=1640797512&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true Also, I'm pretty sure Mathematica uses Yahoo Finance for its `FinancialData[...]` so why not just use that?

Comment: @flinty FinancialData[...] doesn't handle dividends correctly. I hadn't thought to use/look for the download link, so I think that'll work. I'm going to leave the question up in case there are other infinite scrolling websites that others are have or are looking for solutions to working with. Thanks!!

Comment: This has already been asked about here [(245271)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245271/scroll-to-end-of-page-with-webexecute)

Comment: You will need something like this: `session = StartWebSession[];
WebExecute[session, 
  "OpenPage" -> "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL"];
WebExecute[session, 
  "JavascriptExecute" -> 
   "window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);"];
table = WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> "Tag" -> "table"];` However you will probably get the Yahoo cookie banner preventing you from reaching the page. Somehow you need to automatically click accept (ClickElement and js .click() methods don't seem to work for me) or set their EuConsent cookie - again not working for me yet.